How to have optional parameters in a JPQL/JpaRepository?
I'm currently using the following query:
@Query("SELECT new ResumoHistorico(c.id, c.nome, h.isParalisado, COUNT(h), SUM(h.valor), c.isPrioritaria) "
        + "FROM Historico h "
        + "JOIN h.categorias c "
        + "WHERE h.dataRef = :dataRef "
        + "AND h.dataProjecao <= :dataProjecao "
        + "AND c IN :categorias "
        + "AND c.isAgrupador = false "
        + "AND (COALESCE(:agencias, NULL) IS NULL OR h.agencia IN :agencias) "
        + "GROUP BY c.id, c.nome, c.isPrioritaria, h.dataPrevisao, h.isParalisado")

The line + "AND (COALESCE(:agencias, NULL) IS NULL OR h.agencia IN :agencias) " is meant to ignore ":agencias" param when it's null. It works fine in the application, but I have a repo test, in which I insert some dummy data to a H2 database, and it fails with this exception:
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Unknown data type: "NULL, ?"; SQL statement:
If I change the line to + "AND (:agencias IS NULL OR h.agencia IN :agencias) " the test works, but not the app: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector}
Is there a better way to work with optional parameters and still make use of JpaRepository?

I reckon that the second version would work if you were using a native query.

I wanted to avoid using native because our database tables and column names are not as readable as the domain names and we can`t change them

What is your DB in the application? There are limits to in memory databases as they don't always function all the same. IMO though you are probably better off with two queries - a one time coding cost and null check vs having to coalesce large lists to check that nothing was passed in.

I'm using Postgres.. that's what I made for this case, a query for a null list and another one for a real list. But there are some other cases where I have multiple possibly nullable lists, which would make it difficult to write all possible combinations and to maintain. In such cases, what options do I have? I've read that I should avoid using in memory databases for integration tests whenever possible. The thing is that we can't create databases that way in test, hml, prod environments
